# Ошибка при добавлении данных на БД Андроид

Tags: android, sqlite

Пишу простой менеджер паролей для изучении работы с базами данный на андроид. Создал активити и метод для добавлении но при нажатии на кнопку Добавить программа закрывается ошибкой. Код для добавлении :

```
public void AddaRecord(View view) {
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("yourpass", new String[]{DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN,
                    DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN},null, null,
            null, null, null) ;

    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);

    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    EditText website = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteName);
    EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

    String sitename = website.getText().toString();
    String login1 = login.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN, sitename);
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN, login1);
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN, pass);
    // Вставляем данные в таблицу
    mSqLiteDatabase.insert("yourpass", null, newValues);


    cursor.close();
}
```

Лог во время появлении ошибки на Стектрейсе Андроид Студио

```
02-03 17:07:43.246 31555-31555/com.nagizade.whatismypass E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.nagizade.whatismypass, PID: 31555
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4135)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4130)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.nagizade.whatismypass.AddRec.AddaRecord(AddRec.java:26)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4130) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Разметка активити добавлении на базу:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Add new password"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/siteName"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Website"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/siteName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/passWord"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add it"
    android:id="@+id/doit"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passWord"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="AddaRecord" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Для изучении БД на Андроид я читал статью на сайте Александра Климова. Его  пример работает а мой код нет. Точнее ето тоже его код просто в его примере данные добавлялись вручную а не из текстовых полей.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы сначала пытаетесь спросить у базы данных что-то

```
Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("yourpass", new String[]{DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN,
                    DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN},null, null,
            null, null, null) ;
```

А потом уже инициализируете базу данных

```
mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Вполне естественно, что если вы спросите у пустого места, "*где моя любимая*", а потом уже поставите на это место **Ясень**, то ничего из этого не выйдет.

Comment: Как говорил один мудрец "Works like a charm". Спасибо

Comment: @RedShaman, я вот прочитал ваш код, похоже действия с курсором вообще лишние, т. к. вы его потом не используете.

Comment: удалить тогда? этот код для експеримента

Comment: @RedShaman, я ж не знаю всей картины, но судя по тому, что вижу - да, он вообще лишний.

Comment: спасибо за замечание удалил курсор. действительно ничего не делал. но при просмотре елементов БД он нужен